# Trouble changing texture of a sprite using script in Godot

Tags: textures, godot, gdscript

I have a Kinetic Body 2D in my game setup that I use to display different kinds of sprites in my dictionary as and when required. To do that, I used this code and it worked:

```
get_node("Pineapple").get_node("Display").set_texture(global_const.pineapple)
```

Where the variable `pineapple` was in this form in `global_const.gd` singleton script -

```
const pineapple = preload("res://Ingredients/Pineapple.png")
```

Later on,  I decided to get rid of using "global_const" variables altogether as I built a dictionary for all the items I wanted to display. The new dictionary now looks like this -

```
const ingredients = [{iname="Pineapple", icon="res://Ingredients/pineapple.png"},
{iname="Cherry", icon="res://Ingredients/cherry.png"},
{iname="Banana", icon="res://Ingredients/banana.png"}]
```

I wanted to modify the code where I used `set_texture` and I did it this way -

```
for item in on_scene_ingredients: #this loops through all the instances of my Kinetic Body 2D.
#they have different values in "iname" to differentiate between each other
    for reference in dictionary.ingredients: #this checks all the items in my library
        if item.iname==reference.iname: #checks for common name to assign the desired icon
                item.get_node("Display").set_texture(reference.icon)
```

I tested if all the variables are correct and if there is any flaw with the logic, but there isn't. 
The only line that is causing the issue is this -

```
item.get_node("Display").set_texture(reference.icon)
```

Godot throws a runtime error -  *Invalid type in function 'set_texture' in base 'Sprite'. Cannot convert argument 1 from String to Object.*

How do I fix this? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dict is a mapping of `String` to `String`. `reference.iname` and `reference.icon` are both strings, so your code comes out to:

```
item.get_node("Display").set_texture("res://Ingredients/pineapple.png")
```

[set_texture](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_sprite.html#class-sprite-property-texture) expects a `Texture` but you are passing a `String`. You need to load your texture before passing it to `set_texture`:

```
item.get_node("Display").set_texture(load(reference.icon))
```

Comment: You just saved me possibly days worth of research. Thank you, you are a gentleman and a scholar.